# Unable to pair Samsung with Sony Headphone

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-8

I'm unable to pair my **brand new** Sony WF1000-XM4 with my Samsung Galaxy S8.

First, Sony's official Headphones app detects the headphone immediately, but fails to register with "Connection failed" error.

The Bluetooth method also fails because while my phone detects the headphone immediately, I get "Couldn't connect" error.

Resetting the headphone and restarting the phone have no use.

Assuming this is some kind of compatibility issue I checked the headphone's specifications and found that AVRCP is common with my phone, and my phone supports v1.4, v1.3, v1.5 and v1.6 and I tried all of them with no luck.

Please assist.